# Visual Basic variable validation with do loop

Tags: vb.net

So I'm new to visual basic and I'm doing a project for school the user inputs a number in a textbox(txtnum) to see if the user guesses 1 or more of 3 numbers that are randomly shown. The numbers are only for 1 to 9 and because of that I was trying to make a do loop, kind of what I used in c++, to validate the user's input, if it's a number and if is between 1-9, and after that if displays a message box telling the user why, but after this the msgbox doesn't disappear because it is still with the same variable and i cant update my variable because the msgbox doesn't disappear.

Im using visual basic 2010 express, and doing this project with windows form.

```
Private Sub btplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btplay.Click
        ' A geração de numeros aleatórios inteiros entre 1 e 9

        lbln1.Text = Int(1 + Rnd() * 9) 'generates an integer on first label
        lbln2.Text = Int(1 + Rnd() * 9) 'generates an integer on second label
        lbln3.Text = Int(1 + Rnd() * 9) 'generates an integer on third label

        Do
            Do
                If ((IsNumeric(txtnum.Text) = False)) Then 'check is input is a number
                    MsgBox("Opção inválida!" & vbNewLine & "Por favor insira um número entre 1 e 9!", 0, "Número inválido")
                    txtnum.Clear() 
                    txtnum.Focus()
                End If

            Loop Until (IsNumeric(txtnum.Text) = True) 'segundo loop 

            If ((Int(txtnum.Text) < 0) Or (Int(txtnum.Text) > 10)) Then 'check if input on gap
                MsgBox("Opção inválida!" & vbNewLine & "Por favor insira um número entre 1 e 9!", 0, "Número inválido")
                txtnum.Clear() 
                txtnum.Focus() 
            End If

        Loop While ((Int(txtnum.Text) < 0) Or (Int(txtnum.Text) > 10)) 


            'Validação dos números e atualização da pontuação
            If txtnum.Text = lbln1.Text And txtnum.Text = lbln2.Text And txtnum.Text = lbln3.Text Then
                lblpontos.Text = lblpontos.Text + 50 ' got 3 numbers right 

            ElseIf (txtnum.Text = lbln1.Text And txtnum.Text = lbln2.Text) Or (txtnum.Text = lbln1.Text And txtnum.Text = lbln3.Text) Or (txtnum.Text = lbln2.Text And txtnum.Text = lbln3.Text) Then
                lblpontos.Text = lblpontos.Text + 25 ' got 2 numbers right

            ElseIf txtnum.Text = lbln1.Text Or txtnum.Text = lbln2.Text Or txtnum.Text = lbln3.Text Then
                lblpontos.Text = lblpontos.Text + 10 'got 1 number right

            ElseIf txtnum.Text <> lbln1.Text And txtnum.Text <> lbln2.Text And txtnum.Text <> lbln3.Text Then
                lblpontos.Text = lblpontos.Text - 5 ' hasnt got any number right
            End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide more code here? I'm not sure why you are using a loop as opposed to an `if...elseif...else` statement

Comment: Is this VB.net or VBA? They are not equivalent.

Comment: Leverage the TextChanged event of the TextBox to validate the entry. You don't need a "game loop" for this.

Comment: @HardCode how do i do that?

Comment: @Warcupine it's visual basic 2010 express

Comment: @jclasley I was using a loop to first check if the input was a number from 1 to 9, because after that it calculates if the number written matches one of the three displayed, and i would like that it only ran the rest of the code after making sure it's a valid number.

Comment: I edited the question tags to reflect this is [vb.net] instead of [vba].

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: How can the user enter one number and match three different random numbers. Of course the random numbers might be duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were validating input in a Console Application you would want to use a Do/Loop, but because Windows Form Applications are event driven you would simply use a conditional If/Then statement.

If you wanted to validate the input as the user is typing then you would use either the TextChanged, KeyUp, or KeyDown event whereas if you wanted to validate the input when the user "does something" (like click a button) you would handle the "something" event (e.g. a Button's Click event). It all just depends on when you want to validate the input. Another alternative is to validate the input in the TextBox's Validating event.

I personally do my control validation whenever the user does something, like clicking  a Button. Here is an example of validating that:

1. The input is a valid Integer
2. The Integer is between 1 and 9

Example:

```
Private Sub ButtonValidate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonValidate.Click
    Dim input As Integer
    Dim isValidInteger As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(txtnum.Text, input)
    If (Not isValidInteger) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Integer.")
    ElseIf (input < 0 OrElse input > 10) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Integer between 1 and 9.")
    Else
        ' input is a number between 1 and 9
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is process validation every time the user presses the button. Additionally the numbers to be guessed should be stored as fields or properties as `Integer` types instead of `String` type in labels. Finally, use the `Integer.TryParse()` to convert the text input into an integer.

```
Public Class Form1

    Shared rng As New Random()

    ' Keep track of the guess count
    Public Property Tries As Integer
    ' Store numbers in properties
    Public Property X1 As Integer
    Public Property X2 As Integer
    Public Property X3 As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        ' Make sure numbers are unique
        Do
            X1 = rng.Next(1, 10)
            X2 = rng.Next(1, 10)
            X3 = rng.Next(1, 10)
        Loop Until X2 <> X1 AndAlso X3 <> X1 AndAlso X2 <> X3

        Label1.Text = String.Empty
        Label2.Text = String.Empty
        Label3.Text = String.Empty

        Tries = 0

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim input = TextBox1.Text
        If input.Length > 0 Then
            If Integer.TryParse(input, x) Then
                If x <= 0 OrElse x >= 10 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Input a single digit.", "Game")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Tries = Tries + 1
                If x = X1 Then
                    Label1.Text = X1.ToString()
                    MessageBox.Show("Guessed 1st Number.", "Game")
                ElseIf x = X2 Then
                    Label2.Text = X2.ToString()
                    MessageBox.Show("Guessed 2nd Number.", "Game")
                ElseIf x = X3 Then
                    Label3.Text = X3.ToString()
                    MessageBox.Show("Guessed 3rd Number.", "Game")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Guess again.", "Game")
                End If

                If Label1.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso Label2.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso Label3.Text.Length > 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Guessed all the numbers in " & CStr(Tries) & " tries.", "Game")
                    TextBox1.Enabled = False
                    Button1.Enabled = False
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Input isn't numeric.", "Game")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: screen]

Comment: IsNumeric? .net has replaced that old vb6 method with much better methods like .TryParse, .Parse etc.

Comment: If you fill the labels on Form.Load it will be fairly easy to guess.

Comment: @Mary the game mechanics are not the issue here. The _op_ may choose to `.Visible = false` or implement what ever they want.

Comment: It is examples like these that give Visual Basic a bad name. A mix between old and new methods, storing numeric values as Strings, incorrectly using methods...

Comment: @David Where exactly in my code I am storing a number as a string? I am explicit in the conversion (using `CStr()`) which is the same as `.ToString()`). I agree that the _op_ needs a data model to store the three numbers and compare, but I just wanted to address the issue of input validation with my post. Also, the "old" method `IsNumeric()` that I used, was just so that the _op_ was familiar with. Yes, `Integer.TryParse()` should be used instead.

Comment: @ja72 You are storing the numeric values in the form's Load event. Ideally what should be done is you should be storing those values at the form level as private variables (either individually or in an array) and then in the Load event you would set the label's Text equal to the respective values calling the ToString method. The way that your code works is if the OP wanted to get the random values they would need to convert the String values back to an Integer which is completely unnecessary if the user would follow have stored the values at the form level.

Comment: @David - See edits I made for a more _modern_ answer :-)